# Progressbar doesn't display correctly

Tags: android-studio, progress-bar

I have problem with ProgressBar because it does not display it properly.

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3LWRfNDCNdBYm5YTFJ2VEw3V3M/view?usp=sharing)

**Code:**

```
 private void setTimer() {

    if(np3.getValue() == 0){
        time_one = (np1.getValue()) + (np2.getValue() * 60);
        totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = time_one * 1000;
    } else {
        time_two = (np1.getValue()) + (np2.getValue() * 60) + ((np3.getValue() * 3600)-3600);
        totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = time_two * 1000;
    }
    np1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    np2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    np3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    timeseconds = 10 * 1000;
}

private void startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {

                if (leftTimeInMilliseconds <= timeseconds) {
                    if(change == false){
                        textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textViewShowTime.setTextSize(20);
                        textViewShowTime.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.style.RedText);
                        change = true;
                    } else{
                        textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        change = false;
                    }
                }

            if(np3.getValue() == 0){
                Date date = new Date(leftTimeInMilliseconds);
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
                String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
                textViewShowTime.setText(String.format(dateFormatted));
                textViewShowTime.setTextSize(40);
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if(progressStatus <100){
                    int end_time = 100 / time_one;
                    progressStatus += end_time;
                    pb.setProgress(progressStatus);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem.

```
new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500)
```

If you want to simulate 1 second why you are **tick it on 500**. It should be **1000**.

Due to this problem your ProgressBar filled fast. Change it to

```
new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 1000)
```

Update this. I don't think you require `change` boolean

```
textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textViewShowTime.setTextSize(20);
textViewShowTime.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),R.style.RedText);
```

Comment: I changed already but then I had a problem with the flashing text to say that it was not what I wanted :/

Comment: I changed and now there is such a thing 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3LWRfNDCNdBSHB6RGRxTUYydXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why? surely I wrote what the problem is in response?